# Moving window along latter 2 dimensions of a 3D NumPy array to obtain 3D chunks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, convolution

I have a 3D NumPy array `a` of shape `(2, 9, 9)` like this one:

```
a = np.array([
       [[4, 5, 1, 3, 8, 8, 0, 6, 6],
        [9, 2, 2, 1, 8, 2, 2, 4, 5],
        [2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4],
        [9, 6, 2, 9, 1, 0, 6, 2, 3],
        [4, 2, 7, 7, 9, 1, 3, 7, 2],
        [5, 8, 9, 4, 6, 3, 1, 6, 7],
        [3, 6, 4, 7, 2, 9, 8, 3, 4],
        [0, 4, 1, 2, 3, 7, 3, 7, 5],
        [6, 9, 2, 6, 0, 0, 5, 1, 4]],

       [[4, 2, 0, 1, 6, 7, 1, 0, 8],
        [1, 5, 3, 6, 4, 2, 4, 8, 3],
        [7, 4, 9, 9, 1, 9, 7, 3, 1],
        [3, 6, 1, 2, 5, 4, 1, 3, 0],
        [3, 3, 6, 6, 9, 8, 4, 2, 8],
        [7, 9, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 7, 4],
        [6, 7, 9, 3, 0, 2, 1, 9, 2],
        [1, 0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 1, 6, 5],
        [4, 4, 7, 8, 3, 7, 0, 4, 7]]])
```

I would like to get 3D chunks of shape `2 × 3 × 3` using a moving window along latter two dimensions (in this case `9 × 9`). The size of the first dimension (I'd call it "depth") is arbitrary. The example of the first chunk would be:

```
>>> array([
       [[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [np.nan, 4, 5],
        [np.nan, 9, 2]],

        [[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [np.nan, 4, 2],
        [np.nan, 1, 5]]])
```

The second would be:

```
>>> array([
       [[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [4, 5, 1],
        [9, 2, 2]],

        [[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [4, 2, 0],
        [1, 5, 3]]])
```

And so on...

I later need to apply a more complicated function to these chunks, not a simple average or such, so I would appreciate a new array with them (I guess that is quite memory intensive, is there a different approach? Possibly vectorized? But it's not necessary)

I tried applying `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` to my case as in [#44305987](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305987/sliding-windows-along-last-axis-of-a-2d-array-to-give-a-3d-array-using-numpy-str) and played around with fancy indexing as in [#15722324](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722324/sliding-window-of-m-by-n-shape-numpy-ndarray), but did not achieve the desired result.

Thanks!

Comment: I posted a general solution to something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53263678/1782792) - you would just need to [`pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) with NaN beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`skimage.util.view_as_windows`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) for this. Since it appears that you want a minimum size of `2` elements for those windowed views, you could assign the array to a larger array of `np.nan`, and take the strided view of the resulting array:

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

i,j,k= a.shape
a_exp = np.full((i,j+2,k+2), np.nan)
a_exp[:,1:j+1,1:k+1] = a
```

Or you could also do the same with [`np.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

```
a_exp = np.pad(a.astype('float'), 
               pad_width=((0,0),(1,1),(1,1)), 
               constant_values=np.nan)
```

And view as strided with:

```
out = view_as_windows(a_exp, (a.shape[0],3,3))
```

---

```
out
array([[[[[[nan, nan, nan],
           [nan,  4.,  5.],
           [nan,  9.,  2.]],

          [[nan, nan, nan],
           [nan,  4.,  2.],
           [nan,  1.,  5.]]],


         [[[nan, nan, nan],
           [ 4.,  5.,  1.],
           [ 9.,  2.,  2.]],

          [[nan, nan, nan],
           [ 4.,  2.,  0.],
           [ 1.,  5.,  3.]]],
         ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the `skimage.util.view_as_windows`, extremely useful! I've been cruising around scikit but never got to this method.

Comment: To be agnostic, use `view_as_windows(a_exp, (1,3,3))[...,0,:,:]` and then  maybe `transpose(1,2,0,3,4)[0,1]` if OP needs in that first, second chunk order. More info - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/

Comment: @Divakar I'll look at that, thanks. I am just interested, do you think you could point to a NumPy solution to the problem? To my best knowledge, `np.convolve` sorts only 1D arrays...

Comment: @janchytry Convolution is for summing. Are you summing those windows? If you are looking to sum, you might want multidim convolution - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html#scipy.ndimage.convolve

Comment: @Divakar No, I do not, that's probably my misconduct of simply moving window vs. convolution kernel. The function I want to apply later is not expressible by a kernel.

Comment: Added as alternative, though unsure of why the strided view could be somewhow dependant, or why do you suggest otherwise? @Divakar

Comment: @yatu I meant agnostic to make it work irrespective of array shape. I suppose you could altternatively do `view_as_windows(a_exp, (a.shape[0],3,3))`.